# Is there a VBA function or plugin for Excel that will let me use arbitrary date formats to parse dates from string?

Tags: microsoft-excel

For instance, given a string like `18:40:59.795Z` I'd like to be able to call `TOTIME(A1, "HH:MM:SS.mmmZ")` or something like that. Time conversion in Excel is a pain; every time I need to do it I have to do string parsing with `MID` etc. Surely there's a better way?

MacOS preferred.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can I suggest trying [XL Wings Python for Excel](https://www.xlwings.org/) it allows you to use python as an alternative to VBA and the python `datetime` functions library will allow you to do exactly what you are looking for with `datetime.datetime.strptime()` - see [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#strftime-strptime-behavior) for the format information.

Python for Excel is:

- Free, Gratis & Open Source
- Depends on you having an installation of [python](http://www.python.org) which is itself free
- Works on Windows or OS-X
- Allows you to create User Defined Functions, (UDFs), *currently Windows only*
- Can do a lot more for you such as using python to fetch data from a database or the web and format it straight into your workbook.

Comment: Crap, forgot to mention I'm on a Mac. Good suggestion though, way better than VBA. But I'd be fine with a chunk of VBA code if it did what I wanted...

Comment: @jcollum - it works on a Mac as well :-)